# Weird NA behaviour in R

Tags: r

I've noticed some strange behaviour when merging dataframes in R.

When merging, I get extra NA rows in the merged dataframe. The don't appear if displaying the dataframe and don't affect the output of `length()`, but become apparent when indexing. There is a workaround, but it isn't particularly satisfying. I'd much rather not have the strange behaviour at all.

This happens using `join()` in the plyr package and may also happen when joining tables in sql queries with RODBC. It may happen with other packages too.

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how to avoid it? I'm using RStudio in winXP and win8, R version 3.0.1.

```
> library(plyr)
> # example adapted from http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html
> 
> a <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq(1, 4, 1), c("Pirate", "Monkey", "Ninja", "Spaghetti")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> names(a) <- c("a.id", "name")
> a
  a.id      name
1    1    Pirate
2    2    Monkey
3    3     Ninja
4    4 Spaghetti
> 
> b <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq(1, 5, 1), c("Pirate", "Rutabaga", "Darth Vader", "Ninja", "Ninja")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> names(b) <- c("b.id", "name")
> b
  b.id        name
1    1      Pirate
2    2    Rutabaga
3    3 Darth Vader
4    4       Ninja
5    5       Ninja
> 
> z <- join(a, b, by = "name", type = "left", match = "all")
> z
  a.id      name b.id
1    1    Pirate    1
2    2    Monkey <NA>
3    3     Ninja    4
4    3     Ninja    5
5    4 Spaghetti <NA>
> z$compare <- ifelse(z$a.id==z$b.id, 1, 0)
> z # shows dataframe of 5 rows
  a.id      name b.id compare
1    1    Pirate    1       1
2    2    Monkey <NA>      NA
3    3     Ninja    4       0
4    3     Ninja    5       0
5    4 Spaghetti <NA>      NA
> z[z$compare==0 ,] # shows extra rows with row names of NA and NA.1
     a.id  name b.id compare
NA   <NA>  <NA> <NA>      NA
3       3 Ninja    4       0
4       3 Ninja    5       0
NA.1 <NA>  <NA> <NA>      NA
> 
> z <- z[!is.na(z$a.id),]
> z[z$compare==0 ,] # NA rows retained
     a.id  name b.id compare
NA   <NA>  <NA> <NA>      NA
3       3 Ninja    4       0
4       3 Ninja    5       0
NA.1 <NA>  <NA> <NA>      NA

# work around to produce expected output
> z[z$compare==0 & !is.na(z$compare) ,]
  a.id  name b.id compare
3    3 Ninja    4       0
4    3 Ninja    5       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract those rows where `compare` is equal to `0`, you have to exclude the `NA` cases.

Have a look at the column `compare`:

```
z$compare
[1]  1 NA  0  0 NA
```

When you use comparison, i.e., `==`, `NA`s will result in `NA`s. @Codoremifa also showed this in his answer.

```
z$compare == 0
# [1] FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE    NA
```

You should do both (a) compare `compare` with `0` and exclude `NA`s with `!is.na()`:

```
z$compare == 0 & !is.na(z$compare)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This command returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` only.

This output can be used for subsetting:

```
z[z$compare == 0 & !is.na(z$compare), ]
#   a.id  name b.id compare
# 3    3 Ninja    4       0
# 4    3 Ninja    5       0
```

---

**On the behavior of `NA` used for indexing rows of data frames.**

All values will be replaced by `NA` if you use `NA` for indexing:

```
z[NA, ]
#      a.id name b.id compare
# NA   <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
# NA.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
# NA.2 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
# NA.3 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
# NA.4 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
```

(This behavior is due to vector recycling. The command is the same as `z[rep(NA, nrow(z)), ]`.)

If you use an index vector including `NA`s, the corresponding rows will also contain `NA`s only.

For example:

```
z[c(TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE), ]
#      a.id      name b.id compare
# 1       1    Pirate    1       1
# NA   <NA>      <NA> <NA>      NA
# NA.1 <NA>      <NA> <NA>      NA
# 5       4 Spaghetti <NA>      NA
```

As expected, this command returns the first and fifth row, but also two `NA` rows corresponding to the `NA`s in the index vector.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it, thanks very much for your answers. z[z$compare == 0] returns NA rows because NA == 0 is itself neither true nor false, but in fact NA.

Answer (score 1):

Your row subset condition returns an NA which is neither TRUE or FALSE. The NA rows are referring to the second and fifth row of your data.frame.

For instance -

```
> z$compare==0
[1] FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE    NA
> z[NA,]
     a.id name b.id compare
NA   <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
NA.1 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
NA.2 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
NA.3 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
NA.4 <NA> <NA> <NA>      NA
```

Comment: Thanks. Second and fourth or second and fifth? Do the NA rows serve a purpose in R?

Comment: @user2633645 The `NA` rows do not correspond to any row in the data frame. If you use `NA` for indexing, all values in the output will be replaced by `NA`. Have a look at, e.g., `a[NA, ]`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein ok, that makes sense; a[NA] returns NA in four rows and b[NA] returns NA in five which is what one would expect given your explanation. But then why, when indexing on z[z$compare==0, ], does one get NA rows?

Comment: @user2633645, second and fifth., sorry. Indexing on NA is similar to the `z[NA,]` example. You can think of it as R not knowing how to treat those two NAs in the `z$compare==0` vector.